# Auto detect DB instances

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

A client of mine has a software and has many instances of it (one per project). They all share the same SQL server. But there's one DB catalog for each instance. Is it possible, in T-SQL, to auto-detect the catalogs of a SQL server? Or maybe I can send the catalog name in a parameter to the stored proc? I didn't figure out how to do this. It causes an error in the query.

```
SELECT * FROM @CatalogDotTableName
```

Do you have any clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
```

Answer (score 0):

Seek in registry: HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"

Comment: Thanks for your time. I checked and it shows the SQL instances, not catalogs. I'm looking for a listing of the catalogs. Still, it's a good hint